# Handling long words without hyphen (i.e. filenames)

Tags: typography

I'm wondering what would be the best approach for long words that don't have syllables and therfore hyphen would be wrong/bad in this case.

In my case I have a very long filename which I would like to fit in one line without having hyphen in it (because that will basically making it display the "wrong" filename)

here's my striped down example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum 
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis 
\texttt{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext} 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. 

\end{document}
```

this lets my "filename" run over the margins:
[image: over margins]

Of cause one approach would be to use `\linebreak` in front of the name which stretches the spacings a lot on the line prior the filename (which is not looking to good in my eyes):[image: lb]

Probably there is not the one golden approach for this, but I would like to here some opinions / best practises for things like that.

Comment: use `\sloppy` or `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}`

Comment: or a `center` it as a display

Comment: @AndrewSwann `center` what? on which point?

Comment: I mean, just write `\begin{center}\texttt{long_file_name}\end{center}` taking the long word out of the paragraph, much as one would do with an equation.

Comment: ohh great idea thx. But in this case it don't need to be that "prominent", but I can imagine a lot of use cases for this ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several possibilities

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum 
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis 
\texttt{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext} 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. 


\begin{sloppypar}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum 
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis 
\texttt{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext} 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. 
\end{sloppypar}

\begin{flushleft}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum 
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis 
\texttt{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext} 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. 
\end{flushleft}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum 
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis 
\texttt{%
\def\_{\hspace{0pt plus 2pt}\textunderscore\nolinebreak[2]\hspace{0pt plus 2pt}}%
my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext} 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this great overview. Do you have any best practises how to handle the case of long filenames? I kinda prefer the last one.

Comment: @user2798895 depends on the context whether allowing line breaking is allowed, obviously it _looks_ better in a mock up example, but sometimes you require code that can be copied without spurious breaks, so looking worse but being correct is the only option.

Answer (score 4):

Other solutions: use the `url` or the `seqsplit` package. Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url, seqsplit, xcolor}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis
%\texttt{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext}
\textcolor{red}{\url{my_realy_super_long_file_name.ext}}
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate
a, magna.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. \textcolor{cyan}{\seqsplit{my\_realy\_super\_long\_file\_name.ext}} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer
sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo
ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar
at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus.
Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx I defintily like the slim syntax using the `\url` insted of using `\texttt` having the benefit of linebreaks in it.

Comment: @user2798895 Note that, contrary to `sqsplit`, `\url` does not break the word at any point. It uses its own rules, which can be customised.

Comment: `\seqsplit{\texttt{ long_long_name.ext }}` doesn't work ? why ?